# Regex: Split at Next Newline After Word

Tags: jquery, regex, split

I have a statement like this:

> blah
>   blah
>   John did this
>   blah
>   blah
>   John did that
>   etc.

I need this text split at the newline at the end of the lines that start with John. The text after John isn't consistent, but the last line always start with John. Splitting it at 'John' is easy, I just don't know how to say 'split at next newline after the word John'.

```
.split(/(.*?John*?\n)+/g)
```

Above splits it with John becoming its own entry, when I want it to stay with the stuff above it.

*EDIT*

Output should be:

> (blah
>   blah
>   John did this)
>   (blah
>   blah
>   John did that)
>   (etc...

Where the parenthesis represent the split boundary/single array entry.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: please post the desired result, because it's hard to help without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work for you:

```
.split(/.+John.+\n/g)
```

`.` any element

`+` 1 or more times

`John`

`.+` any elements 1 ore more times

`\n` new line

`g` global. Not stop at the first split.

*Edit*

With this: `.split(/(.*?John*?\n)+/g)`, you are matching:

`.*` any elements 0 ore more times

`John*?` John 0 ore more times. `?` doesn't have sense here.

`\n` new line

So this is not matching anything but John again after John, or new line.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
s = "blah\n" +
"blah\n" +
"John did this\n" +
"blah\n" +
"blah\n" +
"John did that";

m = s.match(/[\s\S]*?\bJohn\b[^\n]*/g);

console.log(m);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
["blah
blah
John did this", "
blah
blah
John did that"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var splitted = text.match(/[^]+?John.+\n/g);
```

- `[^]+?` → Any char (but at least one char) reluctant so that it does not consume John
- `.+\n` → Every char in the same line as John

As @anubhava suggested you can use `[\s\S]` for any character, plus surround John with `\b` if you don't the regex to split on, say, `Jonhy`. If you want to match empty strings replace `+` with `*` and if you don't want to include the new line just use `[^\n]+` (all characters except the new line).

---

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/aDvy3/)